# Positive and Negative floating numbers addition PHP: returning exponential number

Tags: php, floating-point, addition

I have many arrays with some positive and some negative numbers in it, and I need to do addition of each of their numbers. If any array is having same numbers which should return 0, but it is returning exponential data.

```
$arr=[
  '-20.91',
  '-34.48',
  '-5.18',
  '34.48',
  '20.91',
  '5.18'
];
$total = 0;
foreach($arr as $ar){
  $total+=$ar;
}
echo $total;
```

This code should give me output as 0 but it is returning **-3.5527136788005E-15**
if I write

```
echo round($total);
```

it shows **-0**.
If possible, can someone please help me to to get the correct output with rounding it to 2? 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the nature of floating point numbers. You may find the `number_format()` function beneficial.

Comment: number_format() is also not working for me

Comment: Echoing `number_format($total, 2)` yields `0.00` for your test case. Since your sample data appears to be two decimal places, `0.00` is what you are looking for correct? Behind the scenes `$total` is still its original value. If you want to force it zero you could have an `if` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> help me to understand this

Floating point numbers using binary encoding cannot represent *exactly* the numbers

'-20.91',
  '-34.48',
  '-5.18',
  '34.48',
  '20.91',
  '5.18'

Instead nearby values are used.  The sum of those is about -3.5527136788005E-15 and not 0.

---

The sum is correct.  The expectation that the computed sum must be 0 is not.

Answer (score 2):

The exponent is -15, the number is incredibly small and is the result of rounding in the [IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) representation of the numbers.

To get an idea of what the issue is you can check this code sample:

```
<?php

$arr=[
  '-20.91',
  '-34.48',
  '-5.18',
  '34.48',
  '20.91',
  '5.18'
];

foreach ($arr as $float) {
    printf("%.30f\n", (float)$float);
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3DhVd)

If you want to avoid this issue you are going to need to round it or make sure you work in numbers that are always sums of powers of 2(so for fractions: 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, etc).

Comment: I want to add these numbers. Just by using printf will not work for me.

Comment: The demo helped me understand the issue, along with the reference to IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754). Thanks!