# PHP arithmetic produces exponent when should produce 0

Tags: php

I have application that is adding a series of numbers.  I expect the numbers to sum to equal `0`, but when PHP processes the math, it comes out to `-1.2789769243682E-13`.  I am curious why this is.  When I perform the math manually it equals zero like expected.

```
<?php

$math = 138.57 + 138.57 + 138.57 + 138.57 + 138.57 + (-673.71) + (-19.14);
echo $math;
//-1.2789769243682E-13
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667791/positive-and-negative-floating-numbers-addition-php-returning-exponential-numbe

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for the link.  The issue was closed as a duplicate before I could follow up, but yes, the link you shared does answer my question (as does the duplicate question answer it was closed with.